# Hide a row of cell when a specific cell is filled

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to hide a row of cell when a specific cell is filled in on Google Sheets

For example:

On row 2 cell E2 is filled in with "1", I want to be able to hide the entire second row.

Is there a possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) for this. This script runs  on every edit (`onEdit`), checks whether the edit is in the 5th column (E), and if the new value is 1, then it hides the row of that cell.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 5 && e.value == 1) {
    e.range.getSheet().hideRows(e.range.getRow());
  }
}
```